# how can i pass array string url in another activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My main activity the video list are shown in my main screen and I set the buttons in drawer, I want to display 4 button in my main screen when i click on url home which can display me url home or url_one how i can pass these links please help me out .

explanation:
in my main screen the home_url are displayed i design four buttons in another activity home button, 1st link,2nd link and favorit button. here i call the links in drawer button i want to attach the buttons in my main activity that show me home button 1st link 2nd link and favorit button when i click on home button that intent me the home_url string and display me the video list same as for other buttons. please help me out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implementsNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Intent.

```
String message = "hello there";    
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the activity you are going to, NextActivity in this case.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

To use it

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);  
textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please note,** **bundle** is one of the key components in Android system that is used for **inter-component communications**. All you have to think is how you can use put your Array inside that bundle.

**Sending side:**

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("17 Fake Street");
        arrayList.add("Phoney town");
        arrayList.add("Makebelieveland");

/* you can add more string values in your arrayList */

        bundle.putStringArrayList("myArrayListKey", arrayList);
        intent1.putExtra(bundle);

        startActivity(intent1);
```

**Receiving side:**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); /* you got the passsed bundle */
ArrayList<String> arrayList = bundle.getStringArray("myArrayListKey");  
/* you got the your passed ArrayList<String> */

/* now you can process your ArrayList<String> which you asked */
```